# $3$D vectors question

Tags: solution-verification, vectors, plane-geometry

I have attempted a question from the OCR paper, AS level Further Maths B Core Pure. It's "A vector **v**$=a$**i**+$b$**j**+$c$**k** has magnitude $1$ unit. The angle between **v** and the positive $z$-axis is $60°$, and **v** is parallel to the plane $x-2y=0$. Given that $a,b,c$ are all positive real numbers, find **v**. "

So my attempt goes:

Since the angle to positive $z$-axis is $60°$, $(a\textbf{i}+b\textbf{j}+c\textbf{k})\bullet{\textbf{k}}=|\textbf{v}||\textbf{k}|\cos{60}$ which gives $c=\frac{1}{2}$.

Then, since the magnitude is $1$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, which is $a^2+b^2=\frac{3}{4}$. The next part I'm unsure about, I don't know exactly how to use the fact that it is parallel to the $x-2y=0$ plane. So I just assumed that that means $a-2b=0$.

So that gives $5b^2=\frac{3}{4}$, or $b=\sqrt{\frac{3}{20}}$ and hence $a=\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$.

So could someone please explain how to use the fact that **v** is parallel to the $x-2y=0$ plane, and to further help my understanding, how would I do it if they instead gave that it was perpendicular to the $x-2y=0$ plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $v$ is parallel to the plane $x - 2y = 0$, it is perpendicular to the normal vector of this plane which is $(1, -2, 0)$, hence,

$ a - 2 b = 0 $

and you also have

$ a^2 + b^2 = \dfrac{3}{4} $

Substituting for $ a $ from the first equation into the second equation

$ b^2 + 4 b^2 = \dfrac{3}{4} $

Hence,

$ b = \pm \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{ \dfrac{3}{5} } $

and then

$ a = \pm \sqrt{ \dfrac{3}{5} } $

So the vector $ v = ( \pm \sqrt{ \dfrac{3}{5} } ,\pm \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{ \dfrac{3}{5} }, \dfrac{1}{2} ) $

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct, "parallel to" means "inside". The distinction could be because the plane is part of the point space while the vector is an element of the translations space. Another way to express this is that the vector is tangent to the plane. In a non-curved situation this is more-or-less all the same, but for instance in Lie-groups as point-space these ideas give different results.